# Can't get MemoryRouter to work with @testing-library/react

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-testing-library

I'm trying to test that my router is working as expected. But I can't get the router to point to another location than `/`

Here's my simplified test code.

`App.tsx`

```js
import React from 'react';
import {Route, Switch, BrowserRouter} from 'react-router-dom';

const App: React.FC = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <BrowserRouter>
                <Switch>
                    <Route path={'/test'}>test</Route>
                    <Route path={'/'}>index</Route>
                </Switch>
            </BrowserRouter>
        </div>
    );
};

export default App;
```

`App.test.tsx`

```js
import React from 'react';
import App from './App';
import {MemoryRouter} from 'react-router-dom';
import {render} from '@testing-library/react';


test('renders /test route', async () => {
    const app = render(
        <MemoryRouter initialEntries={['/test']} initialIndex={0}>
            <App/>
        </MemoryRouter>);
    expect(app.getByText(/test/i)).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```

I get the following error message

```
Error: Unable to find an element with the text: /test/i. This could be because the text is broken up by multiple elements. In this case, you can provide a function for your text matcher to make your matcher more flexible.

<body>
  <div>
    <div>
       index
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The problem is, that the component I wanted to test already has a router declared. 
To solve this issue I had to split up the `App` Component into `App` and `Routes`.

For the testing I just have to render the `Routes` component and everything works as expected.

`App.tsx`

```js
import React from 'react';
import {Route, Switch, BrowserRouter} from 'react-router-dom';

export const Routes = () => {
    return (
        <>
            <Switch>
                <Route path={'/test'}> test</Route>
                <Route path={'/'}> index</Route>
            </Switch>
        </>
    )
};

const App: React.FC = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <BrowserRouter>
                <Routes/>
            </BrowserRouter>
        </div>
    );
};

export default App;
```

`App.test.tsx`

```js
import React from 'react';
import {Routes} from './App';
import {MemoryRouter} from 'react-router-dom';
import {render} from '@testing-library/react';


test('renders routes correct', async () => {
    const app = render(
        <MemoryRouter initialEntries={['/test']} initialIndex={0}>
            <Routes/>
        </MemoryRouter>
    );
    expect(app.getByText(/test/i)).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```

Comment: This was so hard to fine! I wish an example like this was added to React-testing-library docs, or React-Router docs. Or both! 

Comment: It's open source. Why don't you add it, @DavidTorres

Answer (score 0):

If you're loading `App` from `index.js`, which was the case when I was running into this issue on a Create React App app, you can also wrap `App` in a `Router` there and then test `App` routes as you'd expect without having to export `Routes` as you've done.

For example (otherwise a stock CRA `index.js`):

```js
// index.js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './app';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Router>
      <App />
    </Router>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

// If you want your app to work offline and load faster, you can change
// unregister() to register() below. Note this comes with some pitfalls.
serviceWorker.unregister();
```